# How does Word / PowerPoint store images internally? Lossy / lossless format?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

If I include a screenshot or a photo in a MS Word document, will it be stored internally in a lossy or a lossless format?

Answer (score 3):

MS Word will not convert the picture so it will be kept in the format you already have it in.

Comment: Ok that explains what happens when I drag an image from Explorer to MS Word. What if I do Print Screen and then Ctrl+V? What format will be used internally for that?

Comment: That is better as a separate question as is not to do with Word

Comment: Replace "MS Word" with "some MS Office application" and I think the question is still valid.

Comment: The point is that it is not internal - Print Screen provides its own form separate from MS OFFice